# Prevent friend from receiving email notification when I post a status on Facebook

Tags: facebook

Why do one of my friends get an email message whenever I update a status on Facebook? I want to stop it, as I don't want him to see my posts any further and I have blocked him from the status. Please suggest how to do that.

Comment: If you've really "blocked" this person, then they won't see any status updates from you, including notifications. I suggest you double-check that you've actually applied the block.

Answer (score 3):

You can either un-friend anyone you wish to prevent from seeing your updates, or you need to create a group of all your friends with whom you want to share you updates and then when you update, select the drop down to the left of the post button and select custom -> share to the group which excludes your friend.

Also, you could make him an acquaintance and share to friends excluding acquaintances.

Answer (score 0):

If your friend has added you on their "Close Friend" smart list, they would be notified about all your Facebook activity. This includes everything - it you post a status or like a photo or comment on a post.

There is nothing you could do about it, unless of-course you explicitly exclude sharing your status with that person - which i don't think is the right solution. This might not stop your friend from following other activity from you, such as liking or commenting on posts.

The Close friends smart list is definitely useful, but it could be creepy if you doubt someone is stalking you.